# Count occurrences in string and output sorted result by ocuurence_count desc, name

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a string:

```
String str = "Charlie Jennifer Charlie Bob Charlie Charlie Bob Jennifer Alice Alice";
```

Need to count name occurrences in the given string and output sorted result by occurrence count (desc), then by name.
Here is my solution:

```
Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
        .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting())).entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue()
                .reversed()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

My question is: do you know more elegant solution using Java Stream API ?

Comment: What's not "elegant" about this, besides its readability?

Comment: I'm using Java 11.
Not elegant = I'm not sure that my solution is the best in respect of shortness and readability

Comment: @Makoto are you saying that you agree the code isn't very readable but question the need for "elegance"? Elegant code is a subjective thing, but I guess the OP may at least want to 1. avoid multiple stream pipelines, 2. do away with the awkward type witness they had to use

Comment: You're not going to get noticeably better than what you have there.

Comment: @ernest_k, thanks for your opinion, right I thought that using multiple stream pipelines is not the optimal solution. Do you have any ideas on how can I improve this solution ?

Comment: @Usarios I think Louis Wasserman has a point. I don't think this can be improved significantly.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there's not really much to improve here.

Possibly, you could collect the results into a `TreeMap` and use lambda to compare by values without calling `reversed()`:

```java
Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
      .collect(groupingBy(w -> w, TreeMap::new, counting()))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Similarly, `toMap` collector could be used instead of `groupingBy` and `counting`:

```java
 Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
       .collect(toMap(w -> w, x -> 1, Long::sum, TreeMap::new))
       .entrySet().stream()
       .sorted((a, b) -> b.getValue().compareTo(a.getValue()))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Why using a `TreeMap`? Thar wouldn't help here, I think, because `TreeMap` sorts entries by key and OP wants them sorted by value

Comment: they will be sorted by value, but TreeMap will maintain their sorting order by key.

Comment: I mean, you first collect to a `TreeMap`, which sorts by key. Then, you stream the entries and sort them by value. Why collecting to a `TreeMap` in the first place?

Comment: I think I now know what you mean... As you first sort by key, then, when you sort by value, whenever there's a tie, entries will already be sorted by key... I think it's better to use the comparator given by OP, so you only sort once

Comment: Yes, but chained value/reversed/key comparators are imho less "elegant" :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *not* using streams is a little bit less verbose but, still, you need to group first and then sort:

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : str.split(" ")) map.merge(s, 1L, Long::sum);
```

Here I'm using the [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to group words by frequency. Now we need to create a list from the entries and sort it:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()
             .reversed()
             .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()));
```

And now we have a list of `Map.Entry` in `list`, sorted as per your requirements.

If you need to create a map from these entries, it should be a `LinkedHashMap`, to preserve *insertion order*:

```
Map<String, Long> sortedByValue = new LinkedHashMap<>();
list.forEach(e -> sortedByValue.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```